# Clear a log file at runtime:Used by another process error

Tags: c#, serilog

I am using serilog framework in my application. In my application when the log file size reaches 2MB, im creating a backup of log file by renaming the existing file from file.log to file.log.bak and creating a new file.log. At runtime i was facing issue reading the log file, "the process logfile is used by another process" error was shown. so i used below code to read the content of serilog file.

```cs
Stream stream = File.Open (_filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader (stream);
string str = streamReader.ReadToEnd ();
```

But now im not able to clear the log file. I get the same error. How do i clear the content of log file at runtime?

Comment: see also cross post in https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file/issues/94

Comment: Are you disposing your copy stream, before you try to clear the log. (stream.Close()) It may have an unclosed file handle   on the log file.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a logger instante as below

```
var _logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .WriteTo.File("Logs/log.log", shared: true)
                .CreateLogger();
```

You will need to dispose it before dealing with current log file

```
_logger.Dispose();
```

Then do needed modifications

```
string str = string.Empty;
using (Stream stream = System.IO.File.Open("Logs/log.log", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        str = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        //.....
    }
}
```

and create new logger instance again so you can continue logging

```
_logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.File("Logs/log.log", shared: true)
    .CreateLogger();
```

Comment: I have tried using _logger.Dispose() still not able to use StreamWriter.

Comment: @Rem San can you share full example code, also make sure that there is no other instance using same log file