# Is there any way to pause Serilog foer some time?

Tags: c#, serilog

There is Serilog in my app. It writes some information to text file, when the app is running. There is an Email form in the app, too. I want to attach last log-files to the message, but I can't because those files are being used by the process.

I've tried to set SHARED flag to true, but that didn't help.

Also, I've had an idea to pause logging by the CloseAndFlush() method, while attaching. But I don't know how to restart it.

```
    private static LoggerConfiguration Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                                                   .MinimumLevel.Information()
                                                   .WriteTo.File(Path.Combine(MailHelper.SerilogPath, $"{Program.CurrentUser.Login}_actions_log_.txt"),
                                                                 rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Hour, shared: true,
                                                                 retainedFileCountLimit: 10);

    public static void CreateLogger()
    {
        Log.Logger = Logger.CreateLogger();           
    }


    public static void PauseLogging()
    {
        Log.CloseAndFlush();
    }
```

The main idea is to easily attach the log-file to the message. Logging must work before and after it.

But know it's blocked by a process.

Comment: You may consider to read the log file and create a temporary file which you can attach to the email and therby dont need to pause the file logging. Is that an option?

Comment: @Hamit Gündogdu I,ve tried, but the file, blocked by a process, is inaccessible for reading, too.

Comment: Ah ok, think there is a solution for that issue, check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9759697/reading-a-file-used-by-another-process. What you need to do is use FileStream as mentioned in that topic

Comment: @Hamit Gündogdu, Thanks)

Comment: You are welcome :) hope it will solve the problem

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55499047/3134112